# Initialize base class property in base vs in derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, architecture

Let's say we have several Actions in our appplication. So we create an `AbstractAction` and, for example, `ActionMove` which will inherit `AbstractAction`.

```
class AbstractAction
{
    /* stuff common for all actions */
    public ActionType actionType;

    public AbstractAction(Unit owner)
    {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}

class ActionMove : AbstractAction
{
    public ActionMove(Unit owner, Vector3 destination) : base(owner)
    {
        /**/
    }
}
```

Now, I and my colleague are having a dispute. He thinks that `actionType` should be assigned inside the `ActionMove` constructor:

```
public ActionMove(Unit owner, Vector3 destination) : base(owner)
{
    actionType = ActionType.Move;
    /**/
}
```

I think that the `AbstractAction` constructor should set the action type that will be supplied by the derived class constructor:

```
public AbstractAction(ActionType actionType, Unit owner)
{
    this.actionType = actionType;
    this.owner = owner;
}

public ActionMove(Unit owner, Vector3 destination) : base(ActionType.Move, owner)
{
    /**/
}
```

He says that my variant is bad, though he can't say why. It's not like I can say it's good, it just feels right for me. So, can you please tell me which way is better and why? Or maybe there is some third way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the other answerers that `ActionType` should be assigned in the base class if it is a common property for all actions. This seems to me a simple question of separation of concerns: If the base class defines the property, then the best course of action is to have the base class handle it. Unless there is a special reason that requires you to set that property from a derived class, I would even recommend making its setter private.

Note that by requiring to supply the action type in the base class constructor you avoid potentially forgetting setting the type when you create a new derived class. The base constructor will then force you to supply it and set it for you.

---

An alternative solution might be to define an abstract property and then implement this in your derived class.

```
abstract class AbstractAction
{
    public abstract ActionType actionType { get; }
}

class ActionMove : AbstractAction
{
    public override ActionType actionType
    {
        get { return ActionType.Move; }
    }
}
```

This solution also makes sure that all derived classes implement the property as you will get compiler warnings when you don't implement the abstract property.

Answer (score 3):

I would also question why you need an ActionType in your base class at all? Is this so your base class can have different behaviour depending on the ActionType (i.e., the type of the derived class)? If so, then a better design would be to use polymorphism, i.e., get rid of the actionType property, and provide abstract methods in the base class instead, which you override in the derived class to implement the derived class specific behaviour.

I appreciate that is a somewhat contrived example, so my comments may not apply to your real code.

Answer (score 2):

If all Actions have actionType it should be in the base class. There isn't a lot of big difference, but I would also look into readability and simplicity. I wouldn't have 2 classes by the way and just one. If actionType is only specific to ActionMove, then actionType should be in ActionMove.

Comment: All actions have ActionType

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with you. As **ActionType** is a common property for all the classes inhereting from **AbstractAction** it should be set in the **AbstractAction** constructor.